# I have a problem with dispatch event in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, dispatch

On the first click the data array received from dispatch is empty, however if i click on the save button one more time it works perfectly fine.

Here what i get from the console from Account.js

[image]

As you can see i get the error false in data with user information which is exactly what i need.

I'm ensure what is wrong here and why it does not work on the first click.

Account.js

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect }  from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

// react-bootstrap components
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  Form,
  Row,
  Col,
} from "react-bootstrap";

import userActions from '../../redux/auth/actions';

const {
  updateAccount,
} = userActions;

function Account() {

  const loggedUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  const user = useSelector(
    state => state.Auth
  );

  const [first_name, setFirstName] = useState(loggedUser.first_name);
  const [last_name, setLastName] = useState(loggedUser.last_name);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(loggedUser.email);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);

  const handleUpdateAccount = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setSuccess(false);
      const obj = {first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, email: email, password: password};
      dispatch(updateAccount(obj));
      console.log(user);
      if(user.data) {
        if(user.data.error == false) {
          setSuccess(true);
        }
      }
  };

  return (
    <>
        <Row>
          <Col offset-md="2" md="8">
            <Card>
              <Card.Header>
                <Card.Title as="h4">Mon Compte</Card.Title>
              </Card.Header>
              <Card.Body>
                <Form onSubmit={handleUpdateAccount}>
                  <Row>
                    <Col className="pl-1" md="4">
                      <Form.Group>
                        <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">
                          Adresse e-mail 
                        </label>
                        <Form.Control
                          value={email} 
                          onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                          type="email"
                        ></Form.Control>
                      </Form.Group>
                    </Col>
                    <Col className="pr-1" md="5">
                      <Form.Group>
                        <label>Mot de passe</label>
                        <Form.Control
                          value={password} 
                          onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                          type="password"
                        ></Form.Control>
                      </Form.Group>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Col className="pr-1" md="6">
                      <Form.Group>
                        <label>Prénom</label>
                        <Form.Control
                          value={first_name} 
                          onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
                          type="text"
                        ></Form.Control>
                      </Form.Group>
                    </Col>
                    <Col className="pl-1" md="6">
                      <Form.Group>
                        <label>Nom de famille</label>
                        <Form.Control
                          value={last_name} 
                          onChange={e => setLastName(e.target.value)}
                          type="text"
                        ></Form.Control>
                      </Form.Group>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>

                  {(user.data && user.data.error) && <div className="error-message mb-2">{user.data.message}</div>}
                  {(success) && <div className="success-message mb-2">Succès</div>}

                  <Button
                    className="btn-fill pull-right mt-3"
                    type="submit"
                    variant="info"
                    disabled={user.isLoading}
                  >
                    {user.isLoading && <span>Mettre à jour...</span>}
                    {!user.isLoading && <span>Mettre à jour</span>}
                  </Button>
                  <div className="clearfix"></div>
                </Form>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
    </>
  );
}

export default Account;
```

saga.js

```
import { all, takeEvery, put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import actions from './actions';
import axios from "axios";


function update_account(data){

  var actionUrl = '/pages/update_account';
  const isLoggedIn = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

  return axios ({
      method: 'POST',
      url: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + actionUrl,
      data: {
        data,
        user_id: isLoggedIn.id
      },
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", "Accept": "application/json" }
  });
}

function* updateAccount(payload) {
  try {
    const resp = yield call(update_account, payload.payload.data);
    if(resp.data.json.error == false) {
      if(resp.data.json.user) {
        // Do something
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(resp.data.json.user));
      }
    }
    yield put(actions.postToApiSuccess(resp.data.json));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(actions.postToApiError(error));
  }
}


export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    takeEvery(actions.UPDATE_ACCOUNT, updateAccount),
  ]);
}
```

reducer.js

```
import actions from './actions';

const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

const initState = { 
  isLoading: false,
  errorMessage: false,
  data: [],
  loggedUser: user
};

export default function reducer(
  state = initState,
  { type, payload }
) {
  switch (type) {
    case actions.UPDATE_ACCOUNT:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
        errorMessage: false
    };
    case actions.UPDATE_COMPANY_ACCOUNT:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
        errorMessage: false
    };
    case actions.POST_TO_API:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
        errorMessage: false
      };
    case actions.POST_TO_API_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        data: payload.data,
        errorMessage: false,
        loggedUser: payload.data.user
    };
    case actions.LOGOUT_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        loggedUser: null,
        data: []
    };
    case actions.POST_TO_API_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        errorMessage: 'There is a problem'
    };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

actions.js

```
const actions = {
  LOGOUT_USER: 'LOGOUT_USER',
  POST_TO_API: 'POST_TO_API',
  UPDATE_ACCOUNT: 'UPDATE_ACCOUNT',
  UPDATE_COMPANY_ACCOUNT: 'UPDATE_COMPANY_ACCOUNT',
  POST_TO_API_SUCCESS: 'POST_TO_API_SUCCESS',
  POST_TO_API_ERROR: 'POST_TO_API_ERROR',

  postToApi: data => {
    return {
      type: actions.POST_TO_API,
      payload: { data },
    };
  },
  updateAccount: data => {
    return {
      type: actions.UPDATE_ACCOUNT,
      payload: { data },
    };
  },
  updateCompanyAccount: data => {
    return {
      type: actions.UPDATE_COMPANY_ACCOUNT,
      payload: { data },
    };
  },
  logoutUser: data => {
    return {
      type: actions.LOGOUT_USER
    };
  },
  postToApiSuccess: data => ({
    type: actions.POST_TO_API_SUCCESS,
    payload: { data },
  }),
  postToApiError: error => ({
    type: actions.POST_TO_API_ERROR,
    payload: { error },
  }),
};
export default actions;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your initialState "data" is an empty array and you are only updating it when actions.POST_TO_API_SUCCESS get trigger.